# precise de default value in definition for swagger

Tags: swagger-editor

Here is my code draft for an Api the important thing is the definition part  :

```
definitions:
  Code:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: string
  Status:
    type: object
    properties:
      status:
        type: string
externalDocs:
  description: Find out more about Swagger
  url: http://swagger.io
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
host: virtserver.swaggerhub.com
basePath: /gupeel/Raven/1.0.0
# schemes:
#  - http
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
schemes:
 - http
```

and here is the interface on the left  :
[image]

My problem is that it returns : 
    {
      "code": "string"
    }

So i would like if it's possible to return a precise example more like : 
    {
      "code": "toto-titi"
    }
instead of just string.

Thanks